# Save Opened App in Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, wps-office

Is there a way to save file, for example, a spreadsheet in WPS Spreadsheet that is opened in GUI thru a terminal command?
I encountered a case when my desktop freezes but some of the work in GUI apps not saved.

Answer (score 0):

It would be application specific and depend on whether the application exposes ways to communicate with it through the command line or D-bus (the `dbus-send` command offers an interface through the terminal). Then, it would still depend if the application allows to save and close a file this way.

It will likely not be obvious to find ways to do this through the command line. Practically, the bottom line with GUI applications remains to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> often enough.

For your information, although this may not work if the GUI is unresponsive, one can send keystrokes to an application through the command line using `xdotool`. For example:

```
xdotool search --name Untitled key ctrl+s ctrl+q
```

would search a window with "Untitled" in the name, and issue a save and then a close command.